# Offset address to be used in dynamic formula

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am trying to identify a cell in excel using VBA which is going to be used to add a dynamic formula.
This is what I have done so far:

`STCELL = Sheets("ADMIN").Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address(False, False)`

The above line gives me cell "H16"

Now I need to offset this address. I thought about this:

`STCELL1 = Range(" & STCELL & ").Offset(1, 0)`

but unfortunately is not working. The results of the STCELL (start cell) should be used in the next line:

`Sheets("admin").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=INDEX(Mapping!$D:$F,MATCH(" & STCELL & ",Mapping!$A:$A,0),1)"`

the address of STCELL is properly read by VBA in the last line, but I need to offset it since the location of the cell where the formula is going to be applied will keep changing.

So, question is, how can I offset the address I have identified with my first line of code?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: `STCELL1 = Range(STCELL).Offset(1, 0).Address(0, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Since it is the [`Range.Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) property, focus on offsetting a `Range`, not the address of a `Range`:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("ADMIN").Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

STCELL = rng.Address(False, False)
STCELL1 = rng.Offset(1).Address(False, False)
```

Comment: Wow BigBen, that was quick.
Your code wasn't only able to solve the issue, but was also easy to read and easy to work with even for a beginner like me.
Thank you for your time, your help is much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome! I'd say the use of a `Range` variable is what makes it easy to read and work with.